# Opencv+python: Same image file gave different average Value in HSV after cvtColor conversion

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, hsv

I am facing the following error when trying to print out the average value from "Value" in HSV.  Image file is in RBG color format and uint8 type

[image: Image1]

> ```
>  RESTART: C:\Users\310293649\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\HSVPLAYING.py
>
> Image 1 V channel average= 138.582907232
> Image 2 V channel average= 255.0
> ```

For the following code, I supposed two of this method will hv the same average V result since its the same images? following images is the result img i print out after conversion.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Anyone kind to explain to me why? Which way of writing is correct if I wanna get the average value of V channel in HSV?

NOTE: I used BGR2HSV conversion eventhough my file is in RGB as i supposed the default mode of imread in OpenCV will read all image file in BGR format?

```
#Image 1
img1 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\310293649\Desktop\17aP5.png', cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow('img1', img1)
hue, sat, val = img1[:,:,0], img1[:,:,1], img1[:,:,2]
a = np.mean(img1[:,:,2])
print('Image 1 V channel average=', a)

#Image 2
img2 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\310293649\Desktop\17aP5.png')
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
hue, sat, val = img2[:,:,0], img2[:,:,1], img2[:,:,2]
b = np.mean(img2[:,:,2])
print('Image 2 V channel average=', b)
```

I am facing another error which I dont understand as well when trying to only print out the average V value from the red color region in image. I got an error in image 4 and again I would like to know which way of writing it is correct?

> Image 3 V channel average= 255.0
>
> > >
> >     Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "C:\Users\310293649\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\HSVPLAYING.py", line 64, in 
> >         cv2.imshow('img4', img4)
> >     cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
> >     >

Below is my code

```
#Image 3
img3 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\310293649\Desktop\17aP5.png')
img3 = img3[100:(100+50), 100:(100+50)]
img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow('img3', img3)
hue, sat, val = img3[:,:,0], img3[:,:,1], img3[:,:,2]
c = np.mean(img3[:,:,2])
print('Image 3 V channel average=', c)

#Image 4
img4 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\310293649\Desktop\17aP5.png', cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img4 = img4[100:(100+50), 100:(100+50)]
cv2.imshow('img4', img4)
hue, sat, val = img4[:,:,0], img4[:,:,1], img4[:,:,2]
d = np.mean(img4[:,:,2])
print('Image 4 V channel average=', d)
```

Comment: `cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\310293649\Desktop\17aP5.png', cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` -- that's not doing what you think it's doing. `COLOR_BGR2HSV` is not meant to be used with `imread`. You're basically passing the value of `40` as the second parameter, so It's still reading BGR.

Comment: @DanMašek  Does that mean the way that I code for Image 2 is giving me correct average V value as it is read in HSV form?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.